# The Embedded Login sample code does not work

Tags: authentication

I did go through the example of [Embedded Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_intro.htm) step by step. I cloned the [source code](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/embedded-login-example) from GitHub and deployed the sample application to my Heroku environment as guided on the page of the source code. Unfortunately the [sample application](https://peaceful-castle-89980.herokuapp.com) simply not work.

Comment: Please be specific with regards to the "not work" part. Detail the actions you performed and what happened (or didn't happen) as a result, along with any errors if applicable.

Comment: Please share the problem you are having, talk about what you tried and what you ended up as a result, be  more specific. Saying that something does not work will not allow any body to sort out your issue. you should add details.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. There are three "Login for more info" buttons on the home page of FIX Coffee Kits. When you click at any of the buttons, it scrolls up to the page top, not the login page of the Salesforce community as expected. Looked into the code, the button action was defined as onclick="SFIDWidget.login()". I have no idea what SFIDWidget is and how it works. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.